# C# Function as parameter - Repeat method structure

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, delegates

I have multiple methods with different signature, and each method has a try-catch block with custom log exception. (Same structure on multiple controllers).

```
public class TestController : BaseController
{
    public static ActionResult One(int param1, string param2)
    {
        try
        {
            // Do something
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogException(e.Message);
            AddModelError(e.Message);
        }
        return View("ViwName1");
    }

    public static ActionResult Two(Date param3, bool param4)
    {
        try
        {
            // Do something
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogException(e.Message);
            AddModelError(e.Message);
        }
        return View("ViwName2");
    }
}
```

I wonder if there's a way to avoid try-catch block for every method and execute another

```
public class TestController : BaseController
{
    public static ActionResult One(int param1, string param2)
    {
        // Do something (*)
        // Call "ActionWithTryCatch" method that has a "function argument" to "Do something (*)"
    }

    public ActionResult ActionWithTryCatch(MyDelegate del, string viewName)
    {
        try
        {
            return del.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogException(e.Message);
            AddModelError(e.Message);
        }
        return View(viewName);
    }
}
```

¿How can I do that? I've seen examples using delegates but I understand that's strongly typed, so didn't find a way to do that. Thanks!

Comment: I can't parse your weird made-up syntax. Are you saying that inside `ActionWithTryCatch`, you want `del.Invoke()` to execute `service.MethodOne(param1, param2);` in `One()`, and `service.MethodTwo(param3, param4);` in `Two()`?

Comment: If so, easy: `public ActionResult ActionWithTryCatch(Action act, String viewName) { try { act(); } catch (Exception ex){...` etc. Call as `ActionWithTryCatch(() => service.MethodTwo(param3, param4), "ViewName2");`

Comment: Or maybe `public ActionResult ActionWithTryCatch(Func<ActionResult> del, string viewName)`? (based on `return del.Invoke();` delegate seem to return `ActionResult`)...

Comment: Side note: action filters may solve your actual problem better...

Comment: Whoops -- my suggestion should be `Func<ActionResult>`/ `return act();`, sorry

Comment: Sorry. I modified the question to understand it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern that you are describing is close to a form of Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP). However, if you just want to apply specific Try Catch error handling logic to all actions on your controller then it's probably not worth it for you to pull in a whole AOP framework. Instead you could leverage the `HandleErrorAttribute` or override the `OnException` method of the controller class.

For example your could write your controller like this:

```cs
public class TestController
{
    private TestService service;

    public TestController(TestService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public ActionResult One(int param1, string param2)
    {
        this.service.MethodOne(param1, param2);
        return View("ViwName1");
    }

    public ActionResult Two(Date param3, bool param4)
    {
        this.service.MethodTwo(param3, param4);
        return View("ViwName2");
    }

    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        LogException(filterContext.Exception.Message);
        AddModelError(filterContext.Exception.Message);

        var errorView = new ViewResult { ViewName = "~/Path/To/Error/View" };
        filterContext.Result = errorView;
    }
}
```

If you wanted to abstract it out even more then you could just move the overridden OnException logic into a base controller class and then have all of your controller inherit from the base controller.

If you want to see some additional methods of unified error handling in MVC then check out this blog too: https://dusted.codes/demystifying-aspnet-mvc-5-error-pages-and-error-logging

**UPDATE**

Per my comment, if you insist on implementing the pattern you are describing you could use this modified version of gilmishal's answer.

```cs
public class TestController
{
    private TestService service;

    public TestController(TestService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public ActionResult One(int param1, string param2)
    {
        return this.ActionWithTryCatch(() => this.service.MethodOne(param1, param2), "ViwName1");
    }

    public ActionResult Two(Date param3, bool param4)
    {
        return this.ActionWithTryCatch(() => this.service.MethodTwo(param3, param4), "ViwName2");
    }

    public IActionResult ActionWithTryCatch(Action action, string viewName)
    {
        try
        {
            action.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogException(e.Message);
            AddModelError(e.Message);
        }

        return View(viewName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's a solution for my purpose, but do you know how can redirect to view from current action? I mean, if there's an error on "One", I wanna redirect to "ViwName1". Thank u so much!!

Comment: The behavior you are describing doesn't seem like a great pattern. Instead of handling exceptions by just wrapping the very top layer of your code in try..catch you should really be try..catching around specific blocks of code where you anticipate an error could happen.So ideally your service should be catching exceptions within itself and its return value should indicate if there was an error. Then you could return to your desired view and display an error message there. I've updated my answer to include an example of how to implement the pattern you are describing if you insist on using it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks for your time and explanation ;)

Answer (score 0):

this method you created won't work properly if you need to pass parameters to this function in js - so I am assuming you are calling only parameterless methods.

in that case you could use `Func<IActionResult>` instead of `MyDelegate`.

```
public TResult ActionWithTryCatch<TResult>(Func<TResult> del, string viewName)
{
    try
    {
        return del.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogException(e.Message);
        AddModelError(e.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

this will be more similar to your javascript implementation, and will return a 500 http result upon unhandledexception.

You should call it like this, if you want `IActionResult` return type -

```
ActionWithTryCatch<IActionResult>(MethodThatReturnsIActionResult, viewName);
```

I recommand you look into [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Can you tell me can I call this function? I don't know how to send "Func<TResult> del" parameter to execute dynamic code. I changed the question to see it in a different way. Thank you.